# How do I set up Malbers Horse Animset Pro with Unity XR Rig

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, virtual-reality

All I need to do is make it so my XR rig can mount with the Horse and control it with the VR joystick. I can not find a single thing related to using the horse in VR. I doubt anyone knows how to do this because it is such an obscure thing.